# fixing page width of Jekyll themes on GitHub Pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

When I'm doing dev on my local machine, the    $(window).width() is returning ~1900px, when I push it to GitHub pages, the value is ~1200px (even though it's in the same browser window).

What I've tried thus far:
* I've read and implemented various tips about style.scss and default themes, but it doesn't seem to be having an impact. 
* I've also cleared the application cache, doing a hard refresh
* am using the commit message to ensure I'm looking at the right version.

It's a single flat page, so ideally it'd just render as-is (no Jekyll theme or anything).

Here is the published GitHub Page:
https://greennomad424242.github.io/3d_data_viewer/?version=f13a77d

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my atom live-server injects code (included below) into the HTML, without that change being shown in the dev code.

I'm unclear why this would change the manifested window width, but it seems to be root reason.

```
<!-- Code injected by live-server -->
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[  <-- For SVG support
if ('WebSocket' in window) {
    (function() {
        function refreshCSS() {
            var sheets = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("link"));
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; ++i) {
                var elem = sheets[i];
                head.removeChild(elem);
                var rel = elem.rel;
                if (elem.href && typeof rel != "string" || rel.length == 0 || rel.toLowerCase() == "stylesheet") {
                    var url = elem.href.replace(/(&|\?)_cacheOverride=\d+/, '');
                    elem.href = url + (url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?') + '_cacheOverride=' + (new Date().valueOf());
                }
                head.appendChild(elem);
            }
        }
        var protocol = window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'ws://' : 'wss://';
        var address = protocol + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '/ws';
        var socket = new WebSocket(address);
        socket.onmessage = function(msg) {
            if (msg.data == 'reload') window.location.reload();
            else if (msg.data == 'refreshcss') refreshCSS();
        };
        console.log('Live reload enabled.');
    })();
}
// ]]>
```